# Git cherry-pick conflict creating tilde file

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I'm trying to create a bot for migrating a git repository from one form to another.

In this process I run `git cherry-pick $commit_hash -X theirs --no-edit --keep-redundant-commits` to cherry-pick changes from a staging branch to my master branch.

Both the HEAD of master and the cherry-picked commit are adding the same file but with different content. I would like the cherry-picked commit to overwrite, hence `-X theirs`.

However, I am getting a conflict, with git adding a second file called `path/to/first_file~[commit hash]...[truncated commit message]`. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `-X theirs` affects only merge conflicts *within an existing file*.<sup>1</sup>  Merge conflicts can also occur as:

- add/add: both sides (`HEAD`, and the to-be-picked/merged commit) are adding the same file.
- modify/delete: one side makes a change to the file, while the other side deletes the file entirely.
- rename/delete: one side renames a file, while the other side deletes the file entirely.

You are getting the first of these, but all three cause Git to stop and need external help to resolve the problem.

> ... with git adding a second file called `path/to/first_file~[commit hash]...[truncated commit message]`

Git does not do this, but various external helper merge tools do.

In any case, you must manually resolve the conflict (by picking which file to add, or mixing the two files as necessary).  To automate this, you will need to write some code—essentially, to write your own merge tool.

---

<sup>1</sup>It is worth emphasizing again that it only affects merge *conflicts*.  For instance, if one side changes `color` to `colour` and the other side changes `orange` to `fruit`, but none of the changes are "too close" to each other to cause any conflict, you may wind up with a file that describes your items as being fruit in colour.  (Usually such changes affect the *same* line, so that they do conflict, so that `-X theirs` picks just one side's change.)

Comment: "Git does not do this, but various external helper merge tools do" What kind of helpers would those be? This happens both on my private Ubuntu 16.04 install and on Heroku. I'm not aware of any external helpers installed. I noticed that this occurs with `git merge` as well.

Comment: Do you have a link detailing the external helpers further? :)

Comment: I never use any of the other tools, but I did check inside the Git source to see if any of its own distributed tools use those file names (and they don't). The Git default is just to stop with a merge conflict, and you would run `git mergetool` to run your custom tool. You can also define custom merge *drivers* through the various config files and `.gitattributes` and those could do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ git status                           # copy the conflicted <file path>
$ git checkout --theirs <file-path>    # accept theirs changes
$ git commit -am 'resolved conflicts'  # fixed conflicts
```